# cannot enable cors in nestJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, cors, nestjs

I'm trying to connect react and NestJS but got cors error
my request from the browser (google chrome) is blocked by cors.
I cannot even log the incoming request!!!!!!
in the browser network tab I see CORS error from xhr
and in the console tab I see

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'localhost:3500/api/v1/users/login' from origin
'http://localhost:3001' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported
for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, chrome-untrusted, https.
Axios Error: Network Error
    at createError (createError.js:16:1)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (xhr.js:84:1)
xhr.js:177 POST localhost:3500/api/v1/users/login net::ERR_FAILED
```

I've tried `{ cors: true }` and `app.enableCors();` and

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    next();
  });
```

and

```
const corsOptions: CorsOptions = {
    allowedHeaders: ['origin', 'x-requested-with', 'content-type', 'accept', 'authorization'],
    credentials: true,
    origin: ['http://localhost:3001', 'http://localhost:3000'],
  }
  app.enableCors(corsOptions);
```

Comment: My frontend is Reactjs and I make HTTP calls using Axios. I think the browser is blocking Axios from sending requests; because I cannot log anything in the NestJs

Comment: Typo, you forgot the `//`, `http://` or `https://` off the front of the URL you are inputting in your client-side code.

Comment: The problem was from here !! I got a headache from not getting the correct result; thanks man

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you're making a request to `localhost:3500/api/v1/users/login`, which has no scheme.

Use `http://localhost:3500/api/v1/users/login` instead